# Plotting locations from database on geographical map (city scale)

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, plot

I have to do the following.

There is a database (SQL Server) with locations (longitude and latitude values).
I need to plot the route on the map (Google or otherwise) based on those locations extracted from database.
Plotting lines and map are on ASP.NET webpage.

What would be the most and cost-effective way to accomplish the task above?

I would highly appreciate your assistance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Write service that generates KML data (it's just xml-file. See http://code.google.com/apis/kml for more docs) and load it using Google Maps API by URL (like in this google sample: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml.html)